# Removing default fields from IdentityServer entities

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I've been playing around with [this quickstart example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage) & have been trying to see how far I can customise the database (I have an existing database I've been half-trying to replicate).

So far I've had some luck with fiddling about with the example, adding new field/column combos is easy; but I'd now like to remove default fields from entities, and their associated columns from the database.

So, focusing on the `IdentityUser` object, I've customised the original in the `ApplicationDbContext` to reflect how I'd like the table to look. The original definition, [I believe](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/IdentityServerWithAspIdAndEF/Data/Migrations/ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs), is as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("IdentityServer4AspNetIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser", b =>
{
    b.Property<string>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    b.Property<int>("AccessFailedCount");

    b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
        .IsConcurrencyToken();

    b.Property<string>("Email")
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    b.Property<bool>("EmailConfirmed");

    b.Property<bool>("LockoutEnabled");

    b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("LockoutEnd");

    b.Property<string>("NormalizedEmail")
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    b.Property<string>("NormalizedUserName")
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    b.Property<string>("PasswordHash");

    b.Property<string>("PhoneNumber");

    b.Property<bool>("PhoneNumberConfirmed");

    b.Property<string>("SecurityStamp");

    b.Property<bool>("TwoFactorEnabled");

    b.Property<string>("UserName")
        .HasMaxLength(256);

    b.HasKey("Id");

    b.HasIndex("NormalizedEmail")
        .HasName("EmailIndex");

    b.HasIndex("NormalizedUserName")
        .IsUnique()
        .HasName("UserNameIndex");

    b.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
});
```

And my override defines the structure as so:

```
// "IdentityServer4AspNetIdentity.Models.ApplicationUser"
ModelBuilder.Entity<User>(E =>
{
    E.Property(P => P.Id)
        .HasColumnName("AccountId")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    E.Property(P => P.ConcurrencyStamp)
        .HasMaxLength(512)
        .IsConcurrencyToken();

    E.Property(P => P.Email)
        .HasMaxLength(512)
        .IsRequired();

    E.Property(P => P.EmailConfirmed)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    E.Property(P => P.NormalisedEmail)
        .HasMaxLength(512)
        .IsRequired();

    E.Property(P => P.NormalisedUserName)
        .HasMaxLength(256)
        .IsRequired();

    E.Property(P => P.PasswordHash);

    E.Property(P => P.SecurityStamp)
        .IsRequired();

    E.Property(P => P.TwoFactorEnabled)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    E.Property(P => P.UserName)
        .HasMaxLength(256)
        .IsRequired();

    E.Property(P => P.Registered)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    E.Property(P => P.LastVisit)
        .IsRequired();

    E.HasIndex(P => P.NormalisedEmail)
        .HasName("IX_Users_NormalisedEmail");

    E.HasIndex(P => P.NormalisedUserName)
        .IsUnique()
        .HasName("IX_Users_NormalisedUserName");

    E.ToTable("Users");
});
```

This override corresponds with this `User` entity:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public int AccountId
    {
        get => base.Id;
        set => base.Id = value;
    }
    public string NormalisedEmail
    {
        get => base.NormalizedEmail;
        set => base.NormalizedEmail = value;
    }
    public string NormalisedUserName
    {
        get => base.NormalizedUserName;
        set => base.NormalizedUserName = value;
    }
    public DateTime Registered { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastVisit { get; set; }

    public AccountDetail UserDetails { get; set; }
    public AccountLockout Lockout { get; set; }
    public PasswordReset PasswordResetRequested { get; set; }
    public Concierge ConciergeAccountFlag { get; set; }
    public NotValidated AccountValidatation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> AssignedRoles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserClaim> ClaimsCollection { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LoginAttempt> LoginAttempts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Token> TokenCollection { get; set; }
}
```

I **thought** that this would be enough to redefine the object and store the data I wanted in the way I wanted it structured, however I'm seeing the following exception when attempting to log in to the example:

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
   SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
   Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.
   Invalid column name 'AccountValidatationAccountId'.
   Invalid column name 'ConciergeAccountFlagAccountId'.
   Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
   Invalid column name 'LockoutEnd'.
   Invalid column name 'NormalizedEmail'.
   Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
   Invalid column name 'PasswordResetRequestedAccountId'.
   Invalid column name 'PhoneNumber'.
   Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.`

I know that `AccountValidatationAccountId`, `ConciergeAccountFlagAccountId` and `PasswordResetRequestedAccountId` are my foreign keys, for the "NotValidated", "Concierge" and "PasswordReset" entities (which I'll paste in shortly) but I'm lost as to why they're being included as columns, and why they're named the way they are.

NotValidated:

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<NotValidated>(E =>
{
    E.Property(P => P.AccountId)
        .IsRequired()
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    E.Property(P => P.ValidationKey)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(128)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    E.Property(P => P.Expires)
        .IsRequired()
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

    E.HasKey(P => P.AccountId);

    E.HasOne(P => P.Account)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<User>(P => P.AccountId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_NotValidated_Users_AccountId");

    E.ToTable("NotValidated");
});

public class NotValidated
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string ValidationKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }

    public User Account { get; set; }
}
```

Concierge:

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<Concierge>(E =>
{
    E.Property(P => P.AccountId)
        .IsRequired()
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    E.HasKey(P => P.AccountId);

    E.HasOne(P => P.Account)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<User>(P => P.AccountId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_Concierge_Users_AccountId");

    E.ToTable("ConciergeMap");
});

public class Concierge
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public User Account { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, PasswordReset:

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<PasswordReset>(E =>
{
    E.Property(P => P.AccountId)
        .IsRequired()
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    E.Property(P => P.OneTimeKey)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(128)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    E.Property(P => P.Expires)
        .IsRequired()
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    E.HasKey(P => P.AccountId);

    E.HasOne(P => P.Account)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<User>(P => P.AccountId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_PasswordReset_Users_AccountId");

    E.ToTable("PasswordReset");
});

public class PasswordReset
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string OneTimeKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }

    public User Account { get; set; }
}
```

I did manage to whittle the list down a bit by trying to *unimplement* the fields I don't want, which results in the error below:

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
   SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
   Invalid column name 'AccountValidatationAccountId'.
   Invalid column name 'ConciergeAccountFlagAccountId'.
   Invalid column name 'NormalizedEmail'.
   Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
   Invalid column name 'PasswordResetRequestedAccountId'.`

I did this by adding this lines of code to the end of the `Users` class, but I think it's disgusting & should definitely not be the way to go about this:

```
public new int AccessFailedCount => throw new NotImplementedException();
public new int Id => throw new NotImplementedException("Use 'AccountId'.");
public new bool LockoutEnabled => throw new NotImplementedException();
public new DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd => throw new NotImplementedException();
public new string NormalizedEmail => throw new NotImplementedException(
    "Use 'NormalisedEmail'."
);
public new string NormalizedUserName => throw new NotImplementedException(
    "Use 'NormalisedUserName'."
);
public new string PhoneNumber => throw new NotImplementedException();
public new bool PhoneNumberConfirmed => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Does anyone have any pointers on where I'm going wrong with specifying and storing my fields? Any ideas on why those foreign key columns are being added would be appreciated too.

Comment: Not really an answer, but if you want to radically change the tables you use, or fields on the tables, or even the storage mechanism, then it might be easier to not bother using the provided quick-start helpers. They are just convenience methods to you get up and running quickly, but are by no means necessary if you are trying to implement your own Identity Provider.

Comment: @Mashton: Unfortunately, this is my first foray into IdentityServer, I think I may have bitten off a little more than I can chew with trying to change things this much with no experience of it

Comment: The bits you're changing here aren't really IdentityServer bits ... they're ASP.NET Identity (with IdSvr helpers and Entity Framework migrations). You can get IdSvr up and running without using these helper, using your own Db access code and your own Identity model if you like. In our use-case, we do use ASP.NET Identity, but don't use EF.